# Performance implications of a large variable table

Tags: performance, drupal

My variable table is filling up.  Now at 1,800 records and increasing, I'm wondering about best practices regarding number of Drupal variables?  Does this have performance implications?

EDIT:  I forgot to ask another part.  Is it true that the Drupal variables from this table are cached?

This is a scaling issue, and I have scaling decisions to make based on answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The more data you have to work with the more PHP memory you will need, so far 1800 records is not a lot (depending what you do with that data - use it in views, as blocks and so on..).
I recomend setting your php memory limit to 128M and you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal load all the rows from the {variable} table in memory for each request, see the code in [variable_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_init/6). The array is stored in cache, to reduce database load (I guess), but it is still fully loaded in memory for each page request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm still wondering if there is a "best practice" regarding the number of variables being loaded into memory?  Is 2000 ok?  is 4000 ok? is 10,000 ok?  I have my php memory limit set to 128M.  BTW: each record is smaller than 300 characters.